# HTML 5 filesystem access Type Error

Tags: javascript, html, html5-filesystem, web-storage

I'm working on a webapp and I'm trying to access directories using the filesystem API. I need to request a quota from the user before accessing the directories according to specification. I should do something like this:

```
...
navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(PERSISTENT, 1024*1024, 
function(gB){
   window.requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, gB, onInitFs, errorHandler);
}, function(e){
   console.log('Error', e);
})
...
```

Everytime I do this I get a `**TypeError: Type error**` message. Please what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

NB: onInitFs and errorHandler have been defined I just didn't include the code here.

Comment: for starters, i don't see onInitFs or errorHandler defined...

Comment: they've being defined... that's not the problem.. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having the same issues and someone posted the solution, found at [filesystem-api-not-working-in-chrome-v27-v29](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17227599/1992129)

```
navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(1024*1024, 
  function(gB){
  window.requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, gB, onInitFs, errorHandler);
}, function(e){
  console.log('Error', e);
})
```

You have to remove the `PERSISTENT` from `navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(...)`

Answer (score 0):

this version, from https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage seems to at least get further along:

```
window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(PERSISTENT, 1024*1024, function(grantedBytes) {
  window.webkitRequestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, onInitFs, errorHandler); 
}, function(e) {
  console.log('Error', e); 
});
```

it's window instead of navigator...

Comment: Yes thank you, this works. By the way the reason i used 'navigator' instead of 'window' is because I keep getting these warning messages:
**'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.**

Comment: You shouldn't use windew.webkitStorageInfo, it's currently deprecated