# Filesystem API not working in Chrome v27 & v29

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, cordova, fileapi

I'm trying to set up a file storage for later use in Phonegap, but debugging in Chrome for now. Going the way as described on [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-file-writing) only lets me request a quota from the user, but the callback when requesting the filesystem is not executed. See:

```
window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(PERSISTENT, 1024*1024*1024, function(grantedBytes) {
    requestFS(grantedBytes);
}, onError);

function requestFS(grantedBytes) {
    window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, function(fs) {
        // ... does not get called ###################################
    }, onError);
}
```

Now Chrome warns me that webkitStorageInfo has been deprecated and there is a new standard out from today https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/quota/raw-file/tip/Overview.html. I tried using navigator.webkitPersistentStorage without success.

Is it possible the filesystem API is not working currently or has been deprecated or is possibly something wrong with my above code?

Below functions also don't do anything, no errors visible:

```
navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.queryUsageAndQuota(function(usage, quota) {
    console.log(arguments);

    navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(1024 * 1024, function(grantedQuota) {
        console.log(arguments);

        window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 1024 * 1024, function(fs) {
            console.log(arguments);
        });
    });
});
```

### UPDATE:

I got [Filer](https://github.com/ebidel/filer.js) by Eric Bidelman working, so something in my code must be wrong, though I can't see a difference between the Filer init method and what I'm doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm running Chorme 27 and the follwoing appears to work, showing the log message indicated

```
function onError () { console.log ('Error : ', arguments); }

navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota (1024*1024*1024, function(grantedBytes) {
  console.log ('requestQuota: ', arguments);
  requestFS(grantedBytes);
}, onError);

function requestFS(grantedBytes) {
  window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, function(fs) {
    console.log ('fs: ', arguments); // I see this on Chrome 27 in Ubuntu
  }, onError);
}
```

Basically I changed `window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota` in your original code to `navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota` and removed the `PERSISTENT` parameter

Comment: But that's exactly what I did, isn't it? I guess the failure was more complex, since I plugged it into an existing extensive application. Anyway, thanks for trying it out and Filer.js got me on the right track.

Comment: I'm running on chrome 27.0.1453.116 and this code is not working .. :\ I'm getting an FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR