# HTML5: Filesystem API Chrome 30 - Unexpected errorHandler call

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, fileapi

I have following code in my app.js:

```
function onInitFs(fs) {
    aGlobalFsRoot = fs.root;
    console.log('04Position');
    alert("Welcome to Filesystem! It's showtime :)"+fs); // Just to check if everything is OK :)
}

function openFS() {
navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota (1*1024*1024, function(grantedBytes) {
  console.log ('test1');
  reqFS(grantedBytes);
}, errorHandler);
}

function reqFS(grantedBytes) {
  window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, function(fs) {
    console.log ('test2');
    alert("Welcome to Filesystem! It's showtime :)"+fs); // Just to check if everything is OK :)
  }, errorHandler);
}

function errorHandler(e) {
  var msg = '';

  switch (e.code) {
    case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
      msg = 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR'+e;
      break;
    case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
      msg = 'NOT_FOUND_ERR'+e;
      break;
    case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
      msg = 'SECURITY_ERR z.B. Speicherplatz wurde abgelehnt.'+e;
      break;
    case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
      msg = 'INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR'+e;
      break;
    case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
      msg = 'INVALID_STATE_ERR'+e;
      break;
    default:
      msg = 'Unknown Error'+e;
      break;
  };

  console.log('Error: ' + msg);
}
```

openFS is called on pageload. The code is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164698/filesystem-api-not-working-in-chrome-v27-v29) topic (where it also doesn't seem to work for newer versions of chrome). I can't get it to work. All the time, the errorHandler is called. It makes no difference if the filesystem already exists or not. The quota seems to work.

I get two different console logs:

1. When accsess is granted by user:

   Error: Unknown Error[object DOMError] app.js:81
2. When access is denied by user:

   test1 app.js:45
   Error: SECURITY_ERR z.B. Speicherplatz wurde abgelehnt.[object FileError] app.js:81

Anyone got this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who comes along this thread... this solution works. The problem was about the cookies. In a freshly installed chrome 30, this works for me.