# How to use navigator instead of window.webkitStorageInfo HTML5 File-system API?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-filesystem, web-storage

So there is a similar post found here [html-5-filesystem-access-type-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116467/html-5-filesystem-access-type-error). However, I'm not very satisfied with the conclusion because I do not feel it actually answered the question - the solution given is the deprecated code solution. Does anyone know how to use `navigator` instead of `window` as the Chrome console is informing to do?

I have been using the following and it works, but the chrome console keeps informing me not to do so because it is deprecated.

**Working Deprecated Code**

```
window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(PERSISTENT, 1024*1024*280, function(grantedBytes) {
    window.webkitRequestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, onInitFs, errorHandler); 
}, function(e) {
    console.log('Error', e); 
});
```

*Note: `onInitFs` and `errorHandler` are both functions defined elsewhere, that work.*

**Console Log** - The message I get in the console is as follows:

```
'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage'
or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.
```

So the best practice would be to stop using the deprecated method. Unfortunately, when I replace `window` with `navigator` it crashes (see below). How does one use `navigator` instead of `window` to access the file system?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Below are two examples with the *current* API.

It uses `navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota` instead of the deprecated `window.webkitStorageInfo.queryUsageAndQuota`:

### Query Quota

```
navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage.queryUsageAndQuota ( 
    function(usedBytes, grantedBytes) {  
        console.log('we are using ', usedBytes, ' of ', grantedBytes, 'bytes');
    }, 
    function(e) { console.log('Error', e);  }
);
```

### Request Quota

```
var requestedBytes = 1024*1024*280; 

navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota (
    requestedBytes, function(grantedBytes) {  
        console.log('we were granted ', grantedBytes, 'bytes');

    }, function(e) { console.log('Error', e); }
);
```

You have to choose either **temporary** (`webkitTemporaryStorage`) or **persistent** (`webkitPersistentStorage`) storage to query.

The current Chrome implementation tracks this specific spec version, which describes things a bit more: http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-quota-api-20120703/

[chromestore.js](https://github.com/summera/chromestore.js/) provides an easier API for this data.

---

To answer your original question, your new code would look like this:

### Request quota and initialize filesystem

```
var requestedBytes = 1024*1024*280; 

navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota (
    requestedBytes, function(grantedBytes) {  
        window.webkitRequestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, onInitFs, errorHandler); 

    }, function(e) { console.log('Error', e); }
);
```

Comment: Hi, I got "[ts] Property 'webkitTemporaryStorage' does not exist on type 'Navigator'" error in typescript.can you pls help me to solve it

Answer (score 10):

The error message tells you to use `navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage` or `navigator.webkitPersistentStorage`  and you try to use `navigator.webkitStorageInfo` which is `undefined`.

UPDATE: 
PERSISTENT should not be passed to `navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage` or `navigator.webkitPersistentStorage` but only to `window.webkitRequestFileSystem`. Then there is no more error. (see: [Filesystem API not working in Chrome v27 & v29](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164698/filesystem-api-not-working-in-chrome-v27-v29))

Comment: Good catch, I was hoping that was going to make things work! Unfortunately, It gave me a different error. I've updated the code above. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

Recently, i've spent some time creating an abstraction layer for the Filesystem API with Persistent Storage called Chromestore.js.  I've fixed this error in the abstraction layer by using the same solution talked about here.  But with this API, there's no need to worry about it and it's clean.

https://github.com/summera/chromestore.js

It provides some additional functionality that is pretty handy as well.  It definitely needs to be expanded upon, which I plan on doing soon.  Any suggestions/feedback is much appreciated!  This should make it easier for those using the FileSystem API. Especially for those trying to store large amounts of data retrieved from remote servers.

Examples and documentation are here: https://github.com/summera/chromestore.js/blob/master/chromestore-api.md

I think this has the potential to be expanded and do some really neat things with data and the Filesystem API.

Cheers!