# Android WebView not loading website

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to load a website in my android app using webview, but the webview does is not rendering the website.

The website is https://www.rbsdigital.com/

The webview that I'm using is from this [github](https://github.com/rflash95/WebViewApp) project .

The logs that I get is:

```
10-12 19:57:14.188 1041-1041/com.teknorial.webviewapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.", source:  (0)
10-12 19:57:14.189 1041-1041/com.teknorial.webviewapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "'webkitIndexedDB' is deprecated. Please use 'indexedDB' instead.", source:  (0)
```

Here's my code. From the github project.

```
private WebView view; 
private static final String RBS_URL = "https://www.rbsdigital.com/";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);

    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    view.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    view.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    view.loadUrl(RBS_URL);
}

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now if I use the default webview like the one from [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html).

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.rbsdigital.com/");
```

The app loads the browser instead of rendering the website from the webview.

If Android webview does not support the website, is it possible to load this by any means?

Comment: add your code..

Comment: Have you tried it with the default WebView?

Comment: share the code...

Comment: try to use default webview and tell us what is the status after used that webview or share us some code how you are displaying that url in webview.

Comment: If i use the default webview, the app switches to the browser for loading the website, however let's say if I load google using the default webview, it loads the google in the webview.

Comment: Fortunately, I tried this project and it worked. Thanks guys. https://github.com/slymax/webview

Answer (score 0):

try this line of code for getting rid of deprecated!

```
navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage.queryUsageAndQuota ( 
function(usedBytes, grantedBytes) {  
    console.log('we are using ', usedBytes, ' of ', grantedBytes, 'bytes');
}, 
function(e) { console.log('Error', e);  });
```

[read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809824/how-to-use-navigator-instead-of-window-webkitstorageinfo-html5-file-system-api)
I hope it will work fine!