# How to check the localstorage usage in Chrome?

Tags: javascript

I am using this script:

```
window.navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage.queryUsageAndQuota(function(used, remaining) {
     console.log('Used space', used);
     console.log('Remaining space', remaining);
   }, function(err) {
     console.warn(err);
   });
```

but I get:

```
undefined
Used space 0
Remaining space 5027736601
```

Comment: Everything working as expected. What's your problem with this code?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the code you are using of for HTML 5 file system api. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17809824). this `window.webkitStorageInfo.queryUsageAndQuota(webkitStorageInfo.TEMPORARY, console.log.bind(console))` also returns same as your code. you can calculate used `localstorage` you can use something like this:

```
var _lsTotal=0,_xLen,_x;for(_x in localStorage){_xLen= ((localStorage[_x].length + _x.length)* 2);_lsTotal+=_xLen; console.log(_x.substr(0,50)+" = "+ (_xLen/1024).toFixed(2)+" KB")};console.log("Total = " + (_lsTotal / 1024).toFixed(2) + " KB");
```

Took it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15720835/4587148).

Chrome allows 5MB of data or 5101 k character as per this [test](http://dev-test.nemikor.com/web-storage/support-test/) so you can calculate the remaining storage.