# Chrome storage quota reporting lower than expected

Tags: api, google-chrome, storage, quota

I've got a situation where there is ~190GB of free disk space available on the system hard drive but when I query the storage quota in Chrome using `navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage.queryUsageAndQuota()` it only reports 186MB as being free.

I have cleared out all of the local database and application storage.  I even completely deleted Chrome and its Application Support folder (mac).

The query shows that only a few kb are in use but only 186MB are free.  What haven't I thought of that would cause this quota to be reporting so low?  Also, it isn't in incognito mode and I made sure that all extensions are disabled

Comment: what does chrome://quota-internals/ say about your profile directory, errors, etc?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809824/how-to-use-navigator-instead-of-window-webkitstorageinfo-html5-file-system-api/29662985#29662985

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to query using chrome and get the entire available disk space? Because I don't believe this is possible using the queryUsageAndQuota() you can only request more or view the current pool size.

Eg mine comes back a little over 1gb when i try

```
navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage.queryUsageAndQuota ( 
function(usedBytes, grantedBytes) {  
    console.log('we are using ', usedBytes, ' of ', grantedBytes, 'bytes');
}, 
function(e) { console.log('Error', e);  }
);
```

[Here is a good article](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage) explaining the pool size, essentially its never going to report more than half of the available disk space and of that any app can only have 20% of that.

If you just have that one 190gb drive you would think you still have around 19gb as the max for the app!

HOWEVER try hitting [chrome://quota-internals/](http://chrome://quota-internals/) and for me i found the disk space to be 12.59 GB which when i do the calculations again comes in around the 1.5gb mark then minus any installed apps and already used cache space brings it to the quota limit i got earlier. So Perhaps check the profile size directory. You can also see any other entries in the Usage and Quota tab.

Comment: I'm not trying to access the full amount of free space, but I should be able to access 20% of half of the free space as you mentioned.  As it stands I am only getting about 1/1000 of the free space allotted. Also, when checking chrome://quota-internals (thanks for that tip btw) it still shows ~190GB free.  The mystery remains...

Comment: @joshontheweb did you ever figure this out, I have seen this on just a single users PC, where it shows 78GB availble via net internals, but only gives around 350MB

Answer (score 1):

> You don't need to ask for more temporary storage as the allocation is
>   automatic, and you can't get beyond the maximum limit (as described in
>   the table).

According to [Managing HTML5 Offline Storage](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage#asking_more) part of the documentation.