# How can I make a really long string using IndexedDB without crashing the browser?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, bloburls

I'm writing a web app that generates a potentially large text file that the user will download, and all the processing is done in the browser. So far I'm able to read a file over 1 GB in small chunks, process each chunk, generate a large output file incrementally, and store the growing output in IndexedDB. My more naïve attempt which kept all the results in memory and then serialized them to a file at the very end was causing all browsers to crash.

My question is two-fold:

1. **Can I append to an entry in IndexedDB (either a string or an array) without reading the whole thing into memory first?** Right now, this:

   ```
   task.dbInputWriteQueue.push(output);
   var transaction = db.transaction("files", "readwrite");
   var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("files");
   var request = objectStore.get(file.id);
   request.onsuccess = function()
   {
       request.results += nextPartOfOutput
       objectStore.put(request.results);
   };
   ```

   is causing crashes after the output starts to get big. I could just write a bunch of small entries into the database, but then I'd have to read them all in to memory later anyway to concatenate them. See part 2 of my question...
2. **Can I make a data object URL to reference a value in IndexedDB without loading that value into memory?** For small strings I can do:

   ```
   var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([myString]), {type: 'text/plain'});
   ```

   But for large strings this doesn't jive too well. In fact, it crashes before the string is loaded. It seems that big reads using `get()` from IndexedDB cause Chrome, at least, to crash (even the developer tools crash).

Would it be faster if I was using Blobs instead of strings? Is that conversion cheap?

Basically I need a way, with JavaScript, to write a really big file to disk without loading the whole thing into memory at any one point. I know that you can give `createObjectURL` a File, but that doesn't work in my case since I'm generating a *new* file from one the user provides.

Comment: Is using the file system API (which was deprecated before it was releated) out of the question?

Comment: Yeah, browser support for writing files using the file system api is abysmal, and our customers expect a file to download.

Comment: What kind of file is this ?

Comment: @JuniusRendel In my case it's a delimited text file which the customer can import into a spreadsheet or a database...

Comment: Why not give a number to your chunk (maybe the number of the line if it's CSV like) and use that ID as key for the DB ?

Comment: @dystroy Storing the output, even in pieces, in the database is not a problem. That would certainly work. However, when the Blob is created to produce the file, all the chunks must be concatenated in memory -- as far as I know -- and my question is how to do that without loading the whole thing into memory, if possible. If not, maybe we need to wait for browser technologies to mature a little more.

Comment: Hi Matt, I'm afraid this is possible using only the file system API on chrome, I've implemented such solution and I was able to create files up to 4GB, other solution would be to send the data to the server and create the file there. Until they add a write function to the File API this won't be possible in the browser.

Comment: As @DeniSpasovski suggests, attempt to "send the data to the server and create the file there". Also, post it, rather than use `GET` as `POST` allows sending more data than `GET`.

Comment: One other direction which might be an option if your target is only desktop browsers - using swf to generate files - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150516/javascript-or-flash-export-to-csv-excel

Comment: @AgiHammerthief Yeah .. I'm gonna wait for that 1-4Gb upload ;<

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20623615/huge-javascript-html5-blob-from-large-arraybuffers-to-build-a-giant-file-in-cl How about compressing file in browser so it won't exceed user's memory size?

Comment: I know it is very bad way of implementation, but you can give user ability to download file in parts (2 to 4 parts). And then he must download one script file that execute on their machine to concatenate file.

Comment: Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20623615/huge-javascript-html5-blob-from-large-arraybuffers-to-build-a-giant-file-in-cl?lq=1 will help for you first question

Answer (score 8):

Storing a Blob will use a lot less space and resources as there is no longer a need for conversion to base64. You can even store "text/plain" objects as blobs:

```
var blob = new Blob(['blob object'], {type: 'text/plain'});
var store = db.transaction(['entries'], 'readwrite').objectStore('entries');

// Store the object  
var req = store.put(blob, 'blob');
req.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log(e);
};
req.onsuccess = function(event) {
    console.log('Successfully stored a blob as Blob.');
};
```

You can see more info here:
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/storing-images-and-files-in-indexeddb/

Chrome has supported this only since summer of 2014: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/07/Blob-support-for-IndexedDB-landed-on-Chrome-Dev so you cannot use this on older versions of Chrome.

Comment: Storing files in blob blows after you store about 1Gb of data.

Comment: I think that until now, you can't put file to be downloaded in js without loading them in the memory. It'll crash anyway

Comment: Using file storage you can, but that API is only available on Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I just reopened the [Chrome bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=230858)  which I submitted 2 years ago and created another bug for the [FF team](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1120107), related to the browser crash when creating a large blob. Generating large files shouldn't be a issue for the browsers.

Comment: Still crashes! damn...